# Invalid time when using custom format momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello I am trying to calculate the difference between a creationdatetime (using the format yyyyMMddhhmm)  of a chatroom and the current time. I'm doing this for a web application so I am using moment js for this. However when i try to parse the datetime from the server (creationtime) and do some calculations with it I get back invalid time my question is where do I go wrong and how do i fix this so i get the time difference back. My code is as follows

```
var roomnamearr = roomName.split('~');
    var creationtime = moment(roomnamearr[0],"yyyyMMddhhmm").format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
    var difference = moment(creationtime).fromNow();
    return difference ;
```

Comment: it contains the roomname for example"Chatroom1" and the time of creation in the above mentioned format for example "201604111335"

Comment: Did you try: `YYYYMMDDHHmm`?

Comment: Jcubic thanks this solved the problem i kinda got lost in al the different formating ways

Answer (score 0):

You got good advice in the comments regarding the tokens, but note that there's no need to be calling to moment twice in this code. You can simply write:

```
var roomnamearr = roomName.split('~');
return moment(roomnamearr[0],"YYYYMMDDHHmm").fromNow();
```